# Book appointment type DateTime datatype with no seconds?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, datetime, datetime-format

I'm a newbie at this DateTime thing.

I am trying to create an application where you can book an appointment so it would require something like this when you book an appointment, "Monday 20 April 8:00AM".
I'm using SQL Server and I need to know how to structure my table and also how to do it in code.

Let say I have a BookingTable with AppointmentTime as DateTime. Would I be able to save "Monday 20 April 8:00AM" type of format into that one data field or do I have to divide it and do some conversions in code or whatever? and I would also like to see a small demonstration with the C# code also.

I really did my best to try explain what my problem is, I'm sorry if its vague or confusing.

Comment: "Monday 20 April 8:00AM" - is not a DateTime, it's a string representation of a DateTime. Ability to use this string representation in `INSERT` statement is depend on a lot of things and the most easier way to know it - is to simply check it. You better choose another string representation if you want to use raw INSERT query (`appointmentTime.ToString("s")` or `$"{appointmentTime:s}"`).

Comment: If you don't want to think about such kind of things - simply use some `ORM framework`, [EntityFramework](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/) for example.

Comment: I would not propose to generate the SQL query manually. Always use parameters when adding user input to be guarded against SQL injection attacks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server does not have a DateTime type without seconds, so they will always be stored in the database. Neither does the .NET framework. Typically, you would just set the seconds of your DateTime to 0 when storing and ignore the seconds in your output, to achieve this.

```
DateTime appointmentDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime appointmentDateToStore = new DateTime(
    appointmentDate.Year,
    appointmentDate.Month,
    appointmentDate.Day,
    appointmentDate.Hour,
    appointmentDate.Minute,
    0);
```

How you store it to the database, depends on your choice of data access layer.

Comment: Thank you, I get the idea now. :)

Comment: Also, will you be working with different time zones? If so, I urge you to always use UTC times. If not, it is probably still a good idea :-)